# Popup to appear on the bottom-right corner of its parent

Tags: wpf, popup, dimensions

I'm trying to design a Popup which will appear on the bottom-right corner of its `PlacementTarget`

Let's admit that you set its `PlacementTarget` to a `Window`, well, the Popup will act as classic toaster notifications.

Given the fact that WPF is not smart enough to provide us a "corner" solution, I'm trying to implement a new control, inheriting from `Popup` , which will place itself at the appropriate location.

Here is my first idea: work on `Loaded` event to determine where should I place the Popup.
Problem? I don't want to give any fixed dimensions to the popup, which is supposed to size itself according to the text displayed.

However, I can't get the `ActualWidth` property when `Loaded` event is raised. 
I can't have it either when `Opened` event is raised.

Here is the draft code so far:

```
public class ExceptionPopup : Popup
{
       public ExceptionPopup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ExceptionPopup_Loaded);
        }

        void ExceptionPopup_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PlacementTarget != null)
            {
                if (PlacementTarget is FrameworkElement)
                {
                    parentWidth = (PlacementTarget as FrameworkElement).ActualWidth;
                    parentHeight = (PlacementTarget as FrameworkElement).ActualHeight;
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnOpened(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.HorizontalOffset = parentWidth;
            this.VerticalOffset = parentHeight;
            base.OnOpened(e);
        }
}
```

Is there any other event I could use to catch what I want here?
I'd basically like to set `HorizontalOffset` to `parentWidth - ActualWidth/2` , same for height :)
Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give 2 pictures, one with the current behavior and one with the desired behavior?

Comment: Usually I set the `PlacementTarget` to either `Bottom` or `Right`, then apply a `LayoutTransform` which shifts the Popup by the remaining value. For example, I might use `Placement=Bottom`, then use a LayoutTransform to shift the popup `(Window.Width - Popup.Width)` to the right, and `Popup.Height` upwards. You might not even need to re-adjust based on the Popup Height/Width becauase MSDN says that Popups are not allowed to be displayed off screen, and it will automatically adjust their placement to keep them visible.

Comment: @Rachel Unfortunately I can't do that. As I said earlier, I don't want to give a fixed size to my `Popup` so in the best-case scenario, `Height` and `Width` should be `NaN`. However I can't work on `ActualHeight` & `ActualWidth` either since in the `OnOpened` method, they are still equal to 0. I can't believe that I'm having trouble just to place a popup on the bottom-right of its parent -__-

Comment: @Damascus Try a `RenderTransform` instead of a `LayoutTransform`. It will get applied after the Popup gets Rendered, so `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` will be greater than 0

Comment: Nice idea @Rachel , it works! Thanks, I had never use `RenderTransform` before, just learned it, thanks again!

Comment: @Damascus Glad that worked :) I posted it as an answer so you can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I set the `PlacementTarget` to either `Bottom` or `Right`, then apply a `RenderTransform` which shifts the `Popup` by the remaining value.

For example, I might use `Placement=Bottom`, then use a `RenderTransform` to shift the popup `(Window.Width - Popup.Width)` to the right, and `Popup.Height` upwards. You might not even need to re-adjust based on the Popup Height/Width becauase MSDN says that Popups are not allowed to be displayed off screen, and it will automatically adjust their placement to keep them visible

Be sure you use a `RenderTransform` instead of a `LayoutTransform`, because `RenderTransforms` get applied after the Popup gets Rendered, so the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` will be greater than 0.